# emberjs + rails, how to specify the route and post a request to rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, routes

How to post a request to rails server when click 'check' button

## rails route

```rb
resources :sentences do
  member do
    get :check
  end
end
```

## rails sentences controller

```rb
class SentencesController < ApplicationController

  def check
    render json: false
  end

end
```

## emberjs route

```rb
App.Router.map ->
  @resource "sentences", ->
    @resource "sentence",
      path: ":sentence_id", ->
        @route "check"
```

## emberjs template

```rb
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="sentence">

  <button {{action 'check'}} class='btn'>Check</button>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like what you're trying to do is going against convention.

Here's how it should be, which is going by the assumption that you are just updating a 'check' variable on your model (correct me if I'm wrong).

On the ember side:

The router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('sentences', function() {
    this.resource('sentence', {path: ':sentence_id'});
  });
});
```

The Controller

```
App.SentenceController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  check: function() {
    var sentence = this.get('model');
    sentence.set('check', true);
    sentence.get('store').commit();
  }
});
```

The template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="sentence">
  <button {{action 'check' on="click"}} class='btn'>Check</button>
</script>
```

Then on the rails side you can get rid of the check action from the routes and controller and just use the default end-points (in this case when you do the commit from the ember app it will PUT the changes to your rails app using `sentences#update` (`/sentences/:id/update.json`).